# Use href in AngularJS table to loop through unique ID

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, angularjs

I'm trying to make dynamic links inside an AngularJS search table.

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        $id=$row['id'];
        $first_name=$row['first_name'];
        $last_name=$row['last_name'];
        $role=$row['role'];
        $email=$row['email'];
        $phone=$row['phone'];
        $team_name=$row['team_name'];

        ?>

        <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">                                           
            <td>{{data.first_name}} {{data.last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{data.team_name}}</td>
            <td>{{data.role}}</td>
            <td>{{data.phone}}</td>
            <td>{{data.to_date}}</td>
            <td>{{data.email}}</td>                 
            <?php echo $id; ?>
            <td><?php echo '<a href="admin/admin_edit.php?id='.htmlspecialchars($row['id']).'">Edit</a>'; ?></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>            
    <?php
    } //closes and stops the loop 
    ?>
</table>
```

So if you look at the last `<td>` tag, that tag should loop through the table and display the unique ID of every person. But for some reason the first person's ID is shown for everyone. Now the weird thing is that if I echo the variable `$id` it will show all the different ID's. If I place `<td><?php echo '<a href="admin/admin_edit.php?id='.htmlspecialchars($row['id']).'">Edit</a>'; ?></td>` on it's own seperate `<tr>` tag then it will link all the unique ID's associated to each person. My question: how do I make it so that the ID's are unique to each person and not a duplicate of one person whilst maintaining the same structure of my table? Any help is appreciated.

Please find an example of how it's like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmwyB.jpg

The first picture show's all the unique ID's showing fine, but the second picture shows 'Edit' with the first ID of '100002486' attached to all of them.

It's extremely weird that this doesn't work because if I put `<td><?php echo '<a href="admin/admin_edit.php?id='.htmlspecialchars($row['id']).'">Edit</a>'; ?></td>` into it's own `<tr>` tag then it will uniquely associate people's ID  onto each line. But putting it inside the `<tr>` tag with everything else will only assign the first person's ID to everything. Please see this visual representation of what I'm trying to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDNx6.jpg

Comment: So for each record from PHP we can have multiple rows? What is list?

Comment: there is a `</tbody>` tag inside your loop, this will generate invalid HTML

Comment: @NDM thanks but this did not solve the problem I'm having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `</tbody>` tag from the loop like @NDM suggested in his comment and then try with using the variable `$id` instead of `$row[$id]` like this:

```
<td><?php echo '<a href="admin/admin_edit.php?id='.htmlspecialchars($id).'">Edit</a>'; ?></td>
```

Comment: thanks for your help but unfortunately this did not work. Its so weird because if I put the `<td><?php echo '<a href="admin/admin_edit.php?id='.htmlspecialchars($id).'">Edit</a>'; ?></td>` into it's own `<tr>` tag then it will work and it will dynamically have the unique ID attached to it

Comment: @Karma Did you remove `</tbody>` from the while loop?

Comment: yes I have removed it from the loop and copied out your line of code but there is no change. As I if I move that line of code within it's own `<tr>` tags then it will link ID's the way I want it, but I have no idea why this isn't working.